# VB.NET change windows system date time

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to change the Windows 8 system datetime with the code example below.

```
Private Structure SYSTEMTIME

    Public year As Short

    Public month As Short

    Public dayOfWeek As Short

    Public day As Short

    Public hour As Short

    Public minute As Short

    Public second As Short

    Public milliseconds As Short

End Structure

<DllImport("Kernel32.dll")> Private Shared Function SetLocalTime(ByRef time As SYSTEMTIME) As Boolean

End Function

Private Sub ChangeDate

            Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
            Dim NewDate As Date = "28-April-1978 22:30:00"
            st.year = NewDate .Year
            st.month = NewDate.Month
            st.dayOfWeek = NewDate.DayOfWeek
            st.day = NewDate.Day
            st.hour = NewDate.Hour
            st.minute = NewDate.Minute
            st.second = NewDate.Second
            st.milliseconds = NewDate.Millisecond

            'Set the new time...
            SetLocalTime(st)
End Sub
```

When I print the result of SetLocalTime, it returns false and the system's datetime does not change. I have tried SetSystemTime function also but it returns 0 and does not change anything too. I am using the admin account on windows.

What should I modify to make this work?

Comment: Take a look here for an example http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setlocaltime

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change system date and time with vb.net on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900950/how-to-change-system-date-and-time-with-vb-net-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any of that to do what you want. You can use `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace to accomplish this. Here's a short example for what you need. **This is tried and tested as well**.

```
Private Sub ChangeDate()
   Dim d As DateTime
   d = "22:30:00"

   Try
      Microsoft.VisualBasic.TimeOfDay = d 'Your time...
      Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateString = New Date(1978, 4, 28) 'The date...
   Catch ex As Exception
      'You might have to run as Administrator...?
   End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The issue was that it will not work if I run the program in VS. I must run the program by run as administrator in order for this to work which does not make sense to me as I am already using the admin account. But your solution was much easier and shorter and it works!

Comment: Sorry to revive somewhat of an old thread, however, to bypass the problem @fwan is having is to run Visual Studio as an administrator.
One quick tip to getting past running Visual Studio as an administrator, manually all the time, is to just go to the installation directory and then Properties > Compatibility > Run this program as an administrator > OK

Comment: Your code is wrong. "DateString" must be a string, not a date. So "04-28-1978" would be valid, but not "New Date(...").

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sShortDate", "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post.