# How to correct system time with a button click in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, time

I have created a time correcting application that corrects the system time when clicking on the "Correct time" button.How do i change the system time to current time.I will use the application for my computer which has wrong time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET change windows system date time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590236/vb-net-change-windows-system-date-time)

Comment: Also this [search query](https://www.google.it/webhp?q=adjust%20system%20time%20vb.net) is very effective. See also [help].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change system date and time with vb.net on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900950/how-to-change-system-date-and-time-with-vb-net-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

```
'create a datetime object with the current time
Dim correctTime = DateTime.Now()
'adjust the time
correctTime.AddSeconds(1)

'set the time on your machine
Try
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.TimeOfDay = correctTime
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Could not set the time. You probably need to run as Administrator to do this. " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
End Try
```

You will need to be running "As Admin" to adjust the time though